# c openmp parallel for inside a parallel region

Tags: c, multithreading, for-loop, openmp

my question is like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493265/for-loop-inside-parallel-region). but i'd like to do something different...

for instance, inside my parallel region i'd like to run my code on 4 threads. when each thread enters the for loop, i'd like to run my code on 8 threads. something like

```
#pramga omp parallel num_threads(4)
{
    //do something on 4 threads
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        //do something on 8 threads in total
    }
}
```

so, is there a way to "split" each (4) running threads into two (new) threads so inside the for loop more (8) threads are running ?

Comment: What you have here - nested parallelism, with one parallel section inside another - is supported by most current OpenMP-enabled compilers, but is normally turned off by default.  You'll need to set the `OMP_NESTED` environment variable to `TRUE`, or in your program call `omp_set_nested(1)`.   See, eg, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8303151/463827)

Comment: @Jonathan Dursi : Vakh asks you to rewrite your comment as an answer. then maybe you can give a a complementary information. just before the end of my for loop, i'd like to synchronize the to threads. but if i add a "barrier" the compiler says : barrier region may not be closely nested inside of work-sharing, critical, ordered, master or explicit task region. How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you have here - [nested parallelism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5270/aewbc/index.html), with one parallel section inside another - is supported by most current OpenMP-enabled compilers, but is normally turned off by default. You'll need to set the `OMP_NESTED` environment variable to `TRUE`, or in your program call `omp_set_nested(1)`. See, eg, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8303151/463827).

To answer your followup question in comments, you don't need a barrier at the end of OpenMP parallel for loops; unless you use the [`nowait` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek5st0e3.aspx), there already is an implicit barrier for synchronization at the end of your `for` loop.  And you can't have a barrier *inside* the for loop; what happens if the loop iterations aren't evenly divided by threads?  You'd end up with some threads being "stuck" waiting at a barrier none of the other threads would get to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and the right way to do it is the one you have chosen: the second for-loop will be split by each 4 threads so that 8 threads *may* execute the inner-most loop concurrently.

Comment: thx but it doesn't seem to work... when i look at the cpu's usage, i always see 4 of them running, but never 8... why ? if i parallelize the outer loop on 8 cpus all of them are running but thats not what i want to do... i need to have to distinct regions with 4 and 8 (2x4) threads...

Comment: And you have 8 cpus on your computer, right? Are you sure the work done by the 8 threads is long enough so that it appears in the monitoring?

Comment: i have 48 cpus... not a joke... and yes it should last long enough to be seen with the top (linux) command... but i'll check it more precisely this afternoon, and i'll let you know

Comment: no it doesn't work... but i've got the answer ! see above comment !

Comment: Good. Ask him to write his comment as an answer and accept it :)