# Parallel Section within Parallel Section in openmp

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to create parallel sections within a parallel section. Logically there should be 3 threads created here. 2 in the first section, and one of them should spawn into 2 threads.

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
    #pragma omp section
    {
        printf("section 1  thread = %d\n",omp_get_thread_num());
        omp_set_num_threads(2);
        #pragma omp parallel sections
        {
            #pragma omp section
            {
                printf("section 1.1.  thread = %d\n",omp_get_thread_num());
            }
            #pragma omp section
            {
                printf("section 1.2  thread = d\n",omp_get_thread_num());
            }
        }
    }
    #pragma omp setion
    {
        printf("section 2 thread = %d\n",omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}
```

The output of the code is:-

section 2 thread = 0 section 1 thread = 1 section 1.1. thread = 0 section 1.2 thread = 0

This means that the thread does not get spawned into two in the first section. Does OpenMP support this recursion?

Comment: Try adding `omp_set_nested(1)`; before your first pragma.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c openmp parallel for inside a parallel region](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830526/c-openmp-parallel-for-inside-a-parallel-region)